# Search page doesn't show up following HttpGet request MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a page that takes in a string that will search a list of vendors. My goal is to output them to a grid list on an HTML page. Oddly enough, the first page loads, and I can break point the code until the return view of the actual list page. However, it never actually loads. It is even more frustrating because if I don't pass the model to the grid page, it gives me the typical "You can't use a null model", but then it still doesn't load the new page. I have tried several versions. The most current is below.

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(String searchString)
    {
        this.searchString = searchString;
        List<VendorInvoice> v = VendorSearches.publicSearch(searchString);
        test = v;
        ViewData.Model = v;
        TempData.Add("test",v);

        return RedirectToAction("Search");

    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {

        List<VendorInvoice> v = (List<VendorInvoice>)TempData["test"]; 

        return View("Search",v);

    }
```

So if I take the v out, then I get the error about not passing the model. If it is there, then nothing will happen. The new page won't load.

Comment: You don't need 2 methods, just the `[HtttpGet]` (add the `string searchString` parameter and make the form `FormMethod.Get`) - then just use `List<VendorInvoice> v = VendorSearches.publicSearch(searchString); return View(v);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HttpPost search action method, you are setting the result data to show in TempData and doing calling the `RedirectToAction` method.

`RedirectToAction` returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. That means, it will be totally new request coming to your search GET action again. Since Http is stateles, it does not have any idea about what you did in your previous request. The data stored in TempData won't be available to this request.

What you should be doing is, similar to your GET action method, simply 
return the result to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(String searchString)
{
    this.searchString = searchString;
    List<VendorInvoice> v = VendorSearches.publicSearch(searchString);
    return View("Search",v);
}
```

That should fix your problem. But as Stephen Muecke mentioned, you can keep just your GET action method for your Initial view and search result view

```
public ActionResult Search(String searchString="")
{
    List<VendorInvoice> v = new List<VendorInvoice>();
    v = VendorSearches.publicSearch(searchString);
    return View("Search",v);
}
```

And your view

```
@model List<VendorInvoice>
@using(Html.BeginForm("Search","YourControllerName",FormMethod.GET)
{
  <input type="text" name="searchString" />
  <input type="submit" />
}
<h2>Results</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p> @item.SomePropertyNameOfYourVendorInvoiceHere </p>
}
```

Comment: I think in the second example you mean `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh Yes ! Thanks for catching that. :) Updated